# Using App.config to automate the current country of the user

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm trying to use the App.config file in my C# console application to automate the country that the user is using the program on. So for instance, if I use the .exe file in the US, the application will recognize the user is the United States.

I'm trying to use this so that way I can validate a list of codes from a file with a full list of country codes from that country.

I found this setting for C++ on MSDN, but could not find a C# equivalent. Does anyone know if C# has an App.config equivalent?

"GetCountryCodeFromCountryName" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee785499(v=cs.10).aspx

Comment: Do you have an "Commerce Server 2000" that this link is related to? Because in a normal C# App.config file there is only what you put into it. You cannot get the country from it if you don't put it there before.

Comment: There's already a lot of stuff built into .NET framework so e.g. date and time formatting work correctly based on the users regional settings, etc. If you could explain how your code is going to act differently based on "the application will recognize the user is [sic] the United States" then we might be able to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: The program is going to read in a specific file based on the country. The file contains a list of all of the zip codes/postal codes depending on the country that the user is in. The program will then read in a file and compare the codes from that file to the official list and see if there are any invalid codes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`RegionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Something like:

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName
```

Would return `US` for a user running in the United States, `GB` for someone in Great Britain, etc.

Comment: This is great! But can you please provide an example how how I would implement this into the App.config file?

Comment: @KennedyTran - it doesn't go in the `app.config` file - it just goes wherever you were planning to write the equivalent of the code that calls `GetCountryCodeFromCountryName`.